# Solar inverter installation

Tags: inverter

A reputed solar installer is telling me that I can install more than 20 A worth of solar on a 100 A Main Service Panel (MSP) which has 100 A busbar rating only. According to him it can be accomplished by installing a subpanel which is rated more than 100 A in its busbar rating but I am not clear - how can a sub-panel have more amperes for its busbar when its feeder is only 100 A?

So according to this scenario, I can have 140 A busbar linked to 100 A MSP (and 100 A busbar in MSP) and 40 A of this is for Solar and 100 A is for existing household needs/appliances/ac etc. Having 40 A reserved for *solar* allows a larger inverter to be installed therefore more panels and higher kW.

Is it possible/How does this work ? I am not an electrical engineer so I don't understand all nuisances.

Comment: the current from the solar flow the opposite direction to the  current to the loads so it tends to cacel those currents out.

Comment: Is upgrading the main service panel out of the question? What make/model is it?

Comment: Also, can you post a photo of the panel? It may be possible that there's another section of Code that can come into play here...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he's right.

Imagine this scenario.  You happen to be "going to town" - air conditioner is cycled on, dryer running, water heater heating and range/oven has the works turned on.  That's 30+30+30+50 = 140 amps* of power from the large appliances.

You are only served by mains power.  OK, the 100A main breaker snaps to protect the bus-bars in the panel.

You are served by mains + solar.  Your house draws 95 amps from the mains, and 45 amps from the solar+inverter (it's a sunny day).  The 100A main breaker does not trip.  The 50A solar breaker does not trip.  **You have 140A moving on that panel with 100A buses**.

Now, if the breakers are cleverly arranged (e.g. solar at the bottom, other loads stacked on the left side, [sides don't matter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/110152/47125)) you might still get away with it, with the solar serving the bottom breakers and the mains serving the top breakers - no point along the bus flowing more than 100A.  **But Code doesn't assume such a happy configuration**.  Hence the requirement.

Move this over into a subpanel with 200A buses, and now 100A of mains can come through from the mains panel (use a subfeed lug "breaker"), and 50A can come off the solar panels, and still cheerfully power 150A of stuff in this 200A-bussed panel.  Happy dappy.

---

* I'm speaking apocryphally. Most appliances must be provisioned for 125% of their actual draw.  Take 24A x 125% = 30A.  Appliance builders intentionally size their appliances to just snake under that requirement, so your A/C, water heater, and dryer probably have a 23A load. Realistically 23+23+23+50 (ranges aren't thus derated since they don't expect you to use all spots continuously), so 119 A, etc.